# What's the best way to remove unused npm and composer packages from Laravel

Tags: laravel, npm, composer-php

I am working on a Laravel application which was developed by a previous developer and they haven't used Laravel Mix but any custom js/css were manually written and included.

There are some packages in composer.json and packages.json which are unused in the application.
Whats the best way/approach to remove these unused packages.

FYI, I have used depcheck npm package to find what npm packages are not being used.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the problem in using the common ways to remove a package?

Comment: I have removed it from composer.json, not sure on steos on how can I remove js packages, considering laravel mix.

Comment: What do you mean by "laravel mix"? I would assume that simply removing unused packages one by one and building your application could help to see whether this causes any problems or not

Answer (score 1):

For composer you just need to `composer remove vendor/package`

And for npm just do `npm uninstall <package-name>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this to remove packages from composer.json. According to the documentation: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#remove

> The remove command removes packages from the composer.json file from
> the current directory.
>
> `php composer.phar remove vendor/package vendor/package2`
>
> After removing the requirements, the modified requirements will be
> uninstalled.